# Python writelines skips first line of raw_input

Tags: python, file, input

I am writing a simple journal program with python. I used `sys.stdin.readlines()` so the user could press enter to start a new paragraph and not have to program quit. The problem is that when it writes the input to the text file it skips the first paragraph they enter. so anythying that they write before starting a new line isn't written to the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

def main(): #begin stand alone program

    print "\nPlease tell me about your day.\n";
    userEntry = raw_input() #assigns user's input
    todayEntry = userEntry
    todayEntry = sys.stdin.readlines()

    print "\nThank you! See you tomorrow!\n"

    with open('journal.txt', 'a') as f: 
        f.writelines(todayEntry) #write user's input to txt file


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() #call to main() and complete program
```

Comment: `userEntry = raw_input()` reads one line, then you assign it to `todayEntry`, then you discard this data and overwrite it with `readlines()` result.
Basically, `raw_input()` is not needed.

Comment: Basically, delete that `sys.stdin.realines()` line. It seems to serve not much purpose. If you want to read in multiple paragraphs,  you likely want a `raw_input` within a `while`, with a `break` on a special command

Answer (score 1):

You're reading input with `userEntry = raw_input()`, so `userEntry` now contains the first line the user enters (because that's what `raw_input()` does). You're then reading more input with `todayEntry = sys.stdin.readlines()`. `todayEntry` now contains whatever else the user enters (returned from `sys.stdin.readlines()`). You're then writing `todayEntry` to a file, so the file contains what the user entered after the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import sys

todayEntry = ""
print "Enter text (press ctrl+D at the last empty line or enter 'EOF'):"

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()

    if not line or line.strip()=="EOF":
        break

    todayEntry += line

print "todayEntry:\n"
print todayEntry
```

sample input:

```
111

222

333
ctrl+D
```

Output:

```
111

222

333
```