# Using generator to collate user inputs on multiple lines

Tags: python, memory, input, generator, eof

I am trying to save some memory here - I am building a program where the user can input a (stacked) list of integers like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
.
.
.
```

The below code works good!

```
input_list = []

while True:
    try:
        line = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    input_list.append(int(line))

print(input_list)
```

**But** I would now like to use some sort of generator expression to evaluate the list only when I need, and I *almost* (argh!) got there.

This code works:

```
def prompt_user():

    while True:
        try:
            line = input()

        except EOFError:
            print(line)
            break

        yield line

input_list = (int(line) for line in prompt_user())

print(list(input_list))
```

with one only quack: the last integer input by the user is always omitted. So for instance (the `^D` is me typing CTRL+D at the console from a pycharm debugger):

```
1
2
3
4^D  
3   # ==> seems like after the EOF was detected the integer on the same 
    #     line got completely discarded
[1, 2, 3]
```

I don't really know how to go further.

Comment: You have to hit enter first, *then* type Ctrl-D. Before you hit enter, the terminal isn't actually reading 4 to include it in the process's standard input.

Comment: ofc it worked! ahaha thank a lot fellow so-er!

Comment: And once you do that, you don't need to handle the `EOFError` specially, and in fact, it would be much simpler to do something like `yield from sys.stdin` for the entire body of `prompt_user`.

Comment: Uhm...I am not sure I understand that. Could you give me an example?

Comment: All you are doing is reading a line from standard input, then yielding it. `sys.stdin` is *already* iterable; you don't need to call `input` repeatedly, as its definition boils down to something like `input = lambda p: return next(sys.stdin)` (ignoring the argument, which is just a prompt written to standard output before reading from standard input).

Comment: To cut to the end: `input_list = map(int, sys.stdin)`.

Comment: :mind_blown_emoji:

Comment: (Actually, I'm cheating, as `input` won't return the trailing newline from the return value, but `int` will silently strip it for you.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213272/discussion-between-tytire-recubans-and-chepner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @chepner and to [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071599/python-writelines-skips-first-line-of-raw-input) I reduced this whole logic to:

```
import sys

N = input()  # input returns the first element in our stacked input. 
input_list = map(int, [N] + sys.stdin.readlines())
print(list(input_list))
```

leveraging the fact that `sys.stdin` is already iterable!